# Error while Installing Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

When install pandas, it requires numpy to be installed and on installing it gives following error:

```
Processing numpy-1.9.1.zip
Writing c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-4x5clr\numpy-1.9.1\setup.cfg
Running numpy-1.9.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-4x5clr\numpy-1.9.1\egg-dist-tmp-rz7g3x
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
Running from numpy source directory.
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-4x5clr\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:
    Atlas libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-4x5clr\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1535: UserWarning:
    Blas libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-4x5clr\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1538: UserWarning:
    Blas sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-4x5clr\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:
    Atlas libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-4x5clr\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1443: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-4x5clr\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1446: UserWarning:
    Lapack sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
error: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

How can i resolve this error?

I installed Visual C++ but when i installed numpy using easy_install numpy i got following error:

I installed Visual C++ and then tried easy_install numpy but i got following error:

```
Writing c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-jh4ada\numpy-1.9.1\setup.cfg
Running numpy-1.9.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_instal                                                                                                                l-jh4ada\numpy-1.9.1\egg-dist-tmp-shcroi
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
Could not locate executable f90
Running from numpy source directory.
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-jh4ada\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1                                                                                                                526: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-jh4ada\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1                                                                                                                535: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-jh4ada\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1                                                                                                                538: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-jh4ada\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1                                                                                                                432: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-jh4ada\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1                                                                                                                443: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\cygwin64\tmp\easy_install-jh4ada\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1                                                                                                                446: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:                                                                                                                 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Could not locate executable efl
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
Could not locate executable g95
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'endian.h': No s                                                                                                                uch file or directory
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(5) : error C2118: negative subscript
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(5) : error C2118: negative subscript
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(5) : error C2118: negative subscript
```

_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol rint referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol trunc referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol exp2 referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol log2     _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **builtin_expect referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2091: function returns function
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'string'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2091: function returns function
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'string'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ''
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(3) : warning C4163: 'attribute_optimize_unroll_loops' : not available as an intrinsic function
    _configtest.c(6) : error C2065: 'attribute_optimize_unroll_loops' : undeclared identifier
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2091: function returns function
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'string'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2091: function returns function
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'string'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ''
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(3) : warning C4163: 'attribute_optimize_opt_3' : not available as an intrinsic function
    _configtest.c(6) : error C2065: 'attribute_optimize_opt_3' : undeclared identifier
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2091: function returns function
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2091: function returns function
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ''
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    _configtest.c(3) : warning C4163: 'attribute_nonnull' : not available as an intrinsic function
    _configtest.c(6) : error C2065: 'attribute_nonnull' : undeclared identifier
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'a'
    _configtest.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
    _configtest.c(3) : warning C4163: '__thread' : not available as an intrinsic function
    _configtest.c(6) : error C2065: '__thread' : undeclared identifier
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol nextafterf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol copysignf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol log2f referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol exp2f referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ldexpf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol frexpf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol hypotf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol atanhf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol acoshf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol asinhf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol expm1f referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol log1pf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol truncf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol rintf referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fabsf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fabsf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol rintf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol truncf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol log1pf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol expm1f referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol asinhf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol acoshf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol atanhf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol hypotf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol frexpf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ldexpf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol exp2f referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol log2f referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol copysignf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol nextafterf referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol nextafterl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol copysignl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol log2l referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol exp2l referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ldexpl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol frexpl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol modfl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fmodl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol powl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol atan2l referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol hypotl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol atanhl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol acoshl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol asinhl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol atanl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol acosl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol asinl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol expm1l referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol expl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol log1pl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol logl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol log10l referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqrtl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol truncl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol rintl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ceill referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol floorl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fabsl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol tanhl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol coshl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sinhl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol tanl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cosl referenced in function main
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sinl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 34 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sinl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cosl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol tanl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sinhl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol coshl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol tanhl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fabsl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol floorl referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ceill referenced in function main
    _configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    _configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol rintl referenced in function main
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(8) : error C2065: 'HAVE_DECL_SIGNBIT' : undeclared identifier
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(8) : error C2065: 'HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE' : undeclared identifier
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(8) : error C2065: 'signbit' : undeclared identifier
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(8) : error C2065: 'isfinite' : undeclared identifier
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'complex.h': No such file or directory
    BUILD_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64', os.name='nt', sys.platform='win32'
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(3) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
    _configtest.c(4) : error C2085: 'static_func' : not in formal parameter list
    _configtest.c(4) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
    _configtest.c(7) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
    _configtest.c(8) : error C2085: 'nostatic_func' : not in formal parameter list
    _configtest.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(3) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow '__inline**'
    _configtest.c(4) : error C2085: 'static_func' : not in formal parameter list
    _configtest.c(4) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
    _configtest.c(7) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow '**inline**'
    _configtest.c(8) : error C2085: 'nostatic_func' : not in formal parameter list
    _configtest.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(7) : error C2065: 'Py_UNICODE_WIDE' : undeclared identifier
    File: build\src.win-amd64-2.7\numpy\core\include/numpy\config.h
    #define SIZEOF_PY_INTPTR_T 8
    #define SIZEOF_OFF_T 4
    #define SIZEOF_PY_LONG_LONG 8
    #define MATHLIB
    #define HAVE_SIN 1
    #define HAVE_COS 1
    #define HAVE_TAN 1
    #define HAVE_SINH 1
    #define HAVE_COSH 1
    #define HAVE_TANH 1
    #define HAVE_FABS 1
    #define HAVE_FLOOR 1
    #define HAVE_CEIL 1
    #define HAVE_SQRT 1
    #define HAVE_LOG10 1
    #define HAVE_LOG 1
    #define HAVE_EXP 1
    #define HAVE_ASIN 1
    #define HAVE_ACOS 1
    #define HAVE_ATAN 1
    #define HAVE_FMOD 1
    #define HAVE_MODF 1
    #define HAVE_FREXP 1
    #define HAVE_LDEXP 1
    #define HAVE_ATAN2 1
    #define HAVE_POW 1
    #define HAVE_XMMINTRIN_H 1
    #define HAVE_EMMINTRIN_H 1
    #define HAVE__MM_LOAD_PS 1
    #define HAVE__MM_LOAD_PD 1
    #define HAVE___DECLSPEC_THREAD_ 1
    #define HAVE_SINF 1
    #define HAVE_COSF 1
    #define HAVE_TANF 1
    #define HAVE_SINHF 1
    #define HAVE_COSHF 1
    #define HAVE_TANHF 1
    #define HAVE_FLOORF 1
    #define HAVE_CEILF 1
    #define HAVE_SQRTF 1
    #define HAVE_LOG10F 1
    #define HAVE_LOGF 1
    #define HAVE_EXPF 1
    #define HAVE_ASINF 1
    #define HAVE_ACOSF 1
    #define HAVE_ATANF 1
    #define HAVE_ATAN2F 1
    #define HAVE_POWF 1
    #define HAVE_FMODF 1
    #define HAVE_MODFF 1
    #define __NPY_PRIVATE_NO_SIGNAL
    #define DISTUTILS_USE_SDK
    #define FORCE_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_FORMATTING
    #define ENABLE_SEPARATE_COMPILATION 1
    #define HAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_DOUBLE_LE 1
    #ifndef __cplusplus
    #define inline __inline
    #endif

```
#ifndef _NPY_NPY_CONFIG_H_
#error config.h should never be included directly, include npy_config.h instead
#endif

EOF
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'inttypes.h': No such file or directory
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(6) : fatal error C1189: #error :  gcc >= 4 required
File: build\src.win-amd64-2.7\numpy\core\include/numpy\_numpyconfig.h
#define NPY_SIZEOF_SHORT SIZEOF_SHORT
#define NPY_SIZEOF_INT SIZEOF_INT
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONG SIZEOF_LONG
#define NPY_SIZEOF_FLOAT 4
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_FLOAT 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_DOUBLE 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_DOUBLE 16
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONGDOUBLE 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_LONGDOUBLE 16
#define NPY_SIZEOF_PY_INTPTR_T 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_OFF_T 4
#define NPY_SIZEOF_PY_LONG_LONG 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONGLONG 8
#define NPY_NO_SIGNAL 1
#define NPY_NO_SMP 0
#define NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISNAN
#define NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISINF
#define NPY_ENABLE_SEPARATE_COMPILATION 1
#define NPY_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN
#define NPY_ABI_VERSION 0x01000009
#define NPY_API_VERSION 0x00000009

#ifndef __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1
#endif

EOF
### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
```

Comment: Well it says: `Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. :)

Comment: What are you using to install Pandas/Numpy?

Comment: Windows is the red-headed stepchild of coding environments (unless you're using .Net or other Windows-only stuff). I'd recommend going [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and downloading a binary. Installing Python libraries in Windows that require compiling C or C++ code is a level of hell.

Comment: Although if you want to continue, you'll also need to install LAPACK (which probably means compiling that from source. In Windows. Have fun with that.)

Comment: I installed Visual C++ and then tried easy_install numpy but i got following error:

Answer (score 2):

EDIT 3: BEST WAY
see if you have pip, if not, it is easy to install
open up cmd.exe
type

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

Try using this installer for numpy from the repository
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/girnt9fk/numpy-MKL-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.exe

and see if you return errors there

EDIT:
There are two major errors here

1. is a problem with the setup.py (or at least easy-install)

   either the script is the problem (can't find files in the directory)

   or the directory downloaded was flawed

   Atlas, Blas, Blassrc, and Lapack sources cannot be found because the

script never found numpy\distutils\site.cfg that would point to these. To fix

this problem Rajat would have to edit the script setup.py and fix the

directory location for site.cfg

2. Rajat may not have the right version of Microsoft Visual C++(2008), he can check

it using a variety of methods, but it wouldn't hurt to download

separately, Rajat can get it from here  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

ALTERNATIVELY, it is likely the exe will work out of box, as someone who

sometimes uses Windows to write python, .exes and .msis are the first thing

I look for, because they have always given the least headaches for me if

they exist

EDIT 2:

I downloaded numpy 1.9.1.zip, in the instructions it says you have to build YOUR OWN site.cfg file. there is more information in a file called site.cfg.example (you can open it with a text editor like Notepad ++, Gedit, &c). From what I understand the the only contents need to be

```
    library_dirs=c:\mingw\lib,c:\atlas\lib
```

for this to work, you need to download the mingw package, you can get that from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/

and you need Atlas, the instructions to install that are here

http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node50.html

make sure these folders go to C:\ or change the directory in site.cfg

the site.cfg you write in a text editor needs to be in PATHTONUMPY-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/

I HIGHLY recommend trying the .exe I've linked. but try these and update if there are more errors

Comment: thanks for the criticism, I have appended my answer to be more complete and helpful

Comment: actually this is the exact problem. I installed visual c++ for python 2.7 and again i tried to install numpy but i got issue same as in point 1

Comment: Thanks for the update Rajat, I have added additional information

Comment: updated answer after running into a problem with a module myself

Answer (score 1):

In these cases I recommend using a Python distribution from other vendors who take care of providing complex packages built for Windows. Seriously, have a look at for instance https://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads. It's free to use without limitations (as long as you do not sell it), it comes with a good installer and it comes with a package manager, where you can just type `pypm install numpy` and `pypm install pandas`.

The main advantage of this method is that it is super fast to re-create your Python environment of choice on any given Windows machine.

There is no disadvantage with such a Python installation, you can still use pip and all other package installation methods you are used to.

Answer (score 1):

Installing pandas via the Anaconda package is the easiest way I've found:http://continuum.io/downloads This installer includes all the dependencies in one streamlined, contained install. I highly recommend it.